# Microsoft Excel - Index Formula breaks when new data is pasted into the range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have created a sheet for my workplace where I'm able to search a product name and it will provide me with the unique identifier for different colours of product using this formula:

`=IFERROR(INDEX('SKU Level DATA Dump'!$A:$A,SMALL(IF('STYLE # Lookup'!$A$2='SKU Level DATA Dump'!$C:$C,ROW('SKU Level DATA Dump'!C:C)-MIN(ROW('SKU Level DATA Dump'!C:C))+1," "),ROW()-1))," ")`

The user will type in the product name into cell A2 and the unique numbers associated with that product name will be shown in column 'C'.
**The problem I'm having is when I'm pasting updated data in the range the index formula begins repeating results.** I've tried all the different paste specials with no luck and I can't wrap my head around why this is happening. 
I figure it's because the product name isn't unique. However, it's worked for the past few weeks but is now failing.

Screenshot that shows where it's working as intended:

[image]

Screenshot once updated data is pasted into the range (**formula breaks here**):

[image]

*How the other columns are calculated:*   From cell A3 down is a vlookup formula referencing the adjacent result in cell C3 and so on. Column 'B' is a vlookup of the adjacent C cells and likewise with column D.

Any advice?

Comment: Y U are pasting,, better copy the formula at new destination,,, and execute it,,, or upload your workbook on cloud / Drop Box and let me examine!

Comment: @RajeshS The data is located on a separate sheet and is purely for referencing. In order to prevent outdated information I will have to paste new data in every now and then. The sheet with the formulas never changes unless cell 'A2' contains text that is recognized by the formulas.

Comment: Hi @Oliver_Miles,, if possible share virus free workbook on cloud/Drop box to examine,, !

Comment: Exactly how are you "pasting" the new data in?  Are you straight copying and pasting, or copying from a different .xlsx file (entire row or column) and using context menu to "insert new cells"?  And do you have a buffer row/column at the ends of your range to preserve continuity?